# Windows Server 2012 not starting when PCIe SSD disk installed

Tags: dell-poweredge, ssd, windows-server-2012-r2, pci-express

I have Dell Power Edge R905 server with Windows 2012 R2 installed. Everything works great until I install Plextor M6e SSD PCIe x2 card. With card inserted into PCIe x4 or PCIe x8 slot, system starts and Windows logo is showing but nothing happen next.

How can I diagnose this problem? How to tell Windows to start without this PCIe disk and enable this disk after system started?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/q/305059/7709

Comment: "How to tell Windows to start without this PCIe disk and enable this disk after system started?" I would give Safe Mode a try (press F8 while booting), it usually disables all non-essential drivers, which may allow you to boot.

Comment: Not working:/ Safe mode hangs... This is strange because this same card in other computer works without problems.